# Displaying a notification in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I am using the following code to show a notification in my android application, but using this, with the notification an activity also shows up (i.e. a black blank screen) I dont want this screen, but just a simple notification and when the user clicks the notification then I want to launch the activity. What should be done to this code?

```
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notify = new Notification(R.drawable.mcube_logo, "Message Sent", Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());

        Intent intent = new Intent(RecieveAlarm.this, otherActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent =PendingIntent.getActivity(RecieveAlarm.this, 1, null, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        notify.setLatestEventInfo(RecieveAlarm.this, "Title", "Details", pendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notify);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use:

```
        Notification not = new Notification(idIcon, text, System.currentTimeMillis());
    PendingIntent pInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, new Intent(ctx, the_class_to_call), 0);

    not.setLatestEventInfo(ctx, app_name, text, pInt);
```

and then not.notify....

Answer (score 0):

use AlertDialog, then launch your desired activity on positive button click